# Page break in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

Does anyone know how to insert a page break like in MS Word? When you write some text and the program decides that there is need for a new page, it inserts a larger break and a new page.

I've asked this on MS developers forum, and I've got an answer about `RichEditTextBlocks` - that I should use it with `RichEditTextBlockOverflow`. However, that is a nice piece of advice for reading multi-page texts. Is there anything like that for `RichTextBox`?

I'm writing my program for Windows Store App in C#. But I think that the technique for this problem is the same in WPF or WinForms. I've searched, but I can't find a solution.

Thank You very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you seek a [flow document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx).  As I recall, flow documents are supported in one form or another in WPF and Winforms basic control libraries.

[image]

Comment: I think that is the closest thing to what I need, although I still dont lnow how to pages look like in MS Word

Comment: @RomanPylypets - If you want to emulate MSWord you can insert a word control directly in your app (I want to say using either VSTO or an activeX control).  You add a reference to the word dll's and then you can use word in the App.  Or, you can configure the flowcontrol with the appropriate settings to do whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Wow, that's great idea I think! I'll try to add reference t oword dlls. Thank you for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answers to a similar question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/902b1cdf-8346-4a79-888c-cd607b1a4ebb/):

An MVP suggested this:

> There is no such thing as a "pagebreak" for RTB.  Page breaks are only relevant when you print to paper.  You'll need a word processor like Word.  Google EM_FORMATRANGE to find out how to print the content of an RTB.

And this proposal got some votes:

```
richTextBox1.SelectedRtf = @"{\rtf1 \par \page}";
```

And some more details from the [Windows Desktop Dev guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which includes this code:

> The following example code prints the contents of a rich edit control
>   to the specified printer.

```
// hwnd is the HWND of the rich edit control.
// hdc is the HDC of the printer. This value can be obtained for the 
// default printer as follows:
//
//     PRINTDLG pd = { sizeof(pd) };
//     pd.Flags = PD_RETURNDC | PD_RETURNDEFAULT;
//
//     if (PrintDlg(&pd))
//     {
//        HDC hdc = pd.hDC;
//        ...
//     }

BOOL PrintRTF(HWND hwnd, HDC hdc)
{
    DOCINFO di = { sizeof(di) };

    if (!StartDoc(hdc, &di))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    int cxPhysOffset = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, PHYSICALOFFSETX);
    int cyPhysOffset = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, PHYSICALOFFSETY);

    int cxPhys = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, PHYSICALWIDTH);
    int cyPhys = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, PHYSICALHEIGHT);

    // Create "print preview". 
    SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETTARGETDEVICE, (WPARAM)hdc, cxPhys/2);

    FORMATRANGE fr;

    fr.hdc       = hdc;
    fr.hdcTarget = hdc;

    // Set page rect to physical page size in twips.
    fr.rcPage.top    = 0;  
    fr.rcPage.left   = 0;  
    fr.rcPage.right  = MulDiv(cxPhys, 1440, GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSX));  
    fr.rcPage.bottom = MulDiv(cyPhys, 1440, GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY)); 

    // Set the rendering rectangle to the pintable area of the page.
    fr.rc.left   = cxPhysOffset;
    fr.rc.right  = cxPhysOffset + cxPhys;
    fr.rc.top    = cyPhysOffset;
    fr.rc.bottom = cyPhysOffset + cyPhys;

    SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)-1);          // Select the entire contents.
    SendMessage(hwnd, EM_EXGETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&fr.chrg);  // Get the selection into a CHARRANGE.

    BOOL fSuccess = TRUE;

    // Use GDI to print successive pages.
    while (fr.chrg.cpMin < fr.chrg.cpMax && fSuccess) 
    {
        fSuccess = StartPage(hdc) > 0;

        if (!fSuccess) break;

        int cpMin = SendMessage(hwnd, EM_FORMATRANGE, TRUE, (LPARAM)&fr);

        if (cpMin <= fr.chrg.cpMin) 
        {
            fSuccess = FALSE;
            break;
        }

        fr.chrg.cpMin = cpMin;
        fSuccess = EndPage(hdc) > 0;
    }

    SendMessage(hwnd, EM_FORMATRANGE, FALSE, 0);

    if (fSuccess)
    {
        EndDoc(hdc);
    } 

    else 

    {
        AbortDoc(hdc);
    }

    return fSuccess;

}
```

Comment: Yes, I found a lot of articles about printing text and showing it in pages. I am though interested in sth like Word - to divide into pages even at the stage when I am writing text. Thank you though for ur answer!